# Upload a video in S3 via Remix

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, video, remix.run

I'm trying to upload a video with Remix, so I took [this example](https://github.com/remix-run/remix/pull/3433) and I have something working.

But when i try to upload an heavy video (a simple image is working though), i have this error

```
MaxPartSizeExceededError: Field "file" exceeded upload size of 3000000 bytes.
```

Here is my Form component

```js
export const action: ActionFunction = async ({ request, params }) => {
  const uploadHandler: UploadHandler = composeUploadHandlers(
    s3UploadHandler,
    createMemoryUploadHandler()
  );
  const formData = await parseMultipartFormData(request, uploadHandler);
  const newDesc = formData.get("title");
  const newFile = formData.get("file");
  
  return json({
    newDesc,
    newFile,
  });
}

const Create = () => {
  const [asset, setAsset] = useState<File | null>(null);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setTitle(event.target.value);
  };

  const onChangeAsset = async (evt) => {
    const file = evt?.target?.files?.[0]

    if (!file) return setAsset(null)
    setAsset(file)
  }

  return (
  <Box>
    <Form method="post" action='/create' encType="multipart/form-data">

    // This an input file component
    <Upload
      sublabel='Add video to upload to S3'
      name='asset'
      onChange={onChangeAsset}
      value={asset}
      maxSize={52000000000}
    />
    
    // This is an input text component
    <TextField
      name='title'
      label="Title"
      value={title}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />

    <Button type='submit'>Submit</Button>
    </Form>
  </Box>
  )
}

export default Create
```

I read [in the documentation](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/remix#unstable_creatememoryuploadhandler)

> **Options:** The only options supported are `maxPartSize` and `filter` which work the same as in `unstable_createFileUploadHandler` above. This API is not recommended for anything at scale, but is a convenient utility for simple use cases.

What is my other option ? How would it be possible to upload videos with Remix ?

Comment: If you can't change `maxPartSize` then you're stuck. I wonder why your error says 3mb is the limit, however their example code (from docs) shows a 5mb attempt...

Comment: PS: Does setting `createMemoryUploadHandler( {maxPartSize: 50_000_000} );` allow you to upload a larger file (50mb or less)?

Comment: I finally got it running, I never changed a thing though. I will share it as soon as i have an explanation